# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes while using fit function in TCN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am extracting features of audio files and using TCN to classify them.

```
# After feature extraction I have the following code:
 
  
  from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input
  from tcn import TCN, compiled_tcn
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding
  
  num_classes = Y.shape[1]
  batch_size = X_train.shape[0]
  num_rows = X_train.shape[1]
  num_columns = X_train.shape[2]
  time_stamp= num_rows * num_columns
  input_dim = 1
  
  X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], time_stamp, input_dim)
  print("The new X_train is:", X_train.shape)
  X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], time_stamp, input_dim)
  print("The new X_test is:", X_test.shape)

  i = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, time_stamp, input_dim))

  o = TCN(nb_filters = 64, kernel_size=3,dilations=[1,2,4], return_sequences=False)(i)  # The TCN layers are here.
  o = Dropout(0.5)(o)
  o = Dense(num_classes, activation = 'sigmoid')(o)
  

  m = Model(inputs=[i], outputs=[o])
  m.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                    metrics=['categorical_accuracy'], 
                    optimizer='adam')
  m.summary()
  
  history = m.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 10)
```

The following are the shapes:

X_train shape: (219, 99, 64)

Y_train shape: (219, 5)

X_test shape: (28, 99, 64)

Y_test shape: (28, 5)

When I use the fit function, I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [219,64] vs. [64,64]
     [[node model_18/dropout_15/dropout/Mul_1 (defined at C:\Users\Aarti\.spyder-py3\tcn_trial.py:226) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2272923]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I can understand that it is because of the shape mismatch, but I don't know how to get rid of it.

**SOLUTION:**

The input shape that I was giving to TCN was the reason behind this error. I modified the shape as follows and got rid of the error:

```
i = Input(batch_shape=(None, time_stamp, input_dim))
```